# Unity C# Load textrue with www

Tags: c#, web, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am making a game that load a level by reading XML. That part works fine but I can't load Textrues. He doesnt give a error or something like that. There is just no textrue, it's a null object.

this is the code that read the xml:

```
void ReadXML(){

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("world/world.xml");

    //load all textrues
    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("textrue");
    _matrial = new Texture[elemList.Count];
    for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++){
        LoadTexture(elemList[i].InnerXml);
        _matrial[i] = loaded;
        //_matrial[i] = Resources.Load(elemList[i].InnerXml) as Texture;
        Debug.Log(_matrial[i] + " <> " + elemList[i].InnerXml);
    }


    ///.... here he loads al object, that works fine

}
```

This is the LoadTexture methode:

```
IEnumerator LoadTexture(string url) {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    loaded = www.texture;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is it maybe because you typo'd "texture" on GetElementsByTagName? Also, the "loaded = www.texture" will never run.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are not actually waiting for the WWW to finish, so the `www.texture` is `null` because it hasn't loaded yet: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/44999/yield-return-www-not-returning.html

Comment: yes it was a typo but I also made the same typo on the xml so that part works. but thanks. The probrlem was indeed the waiting. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to wait until the textare is loaded before I could use it. So the function should looks like this:

```
IEnumerator LoadTexture(string url) {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    while (!www.isDone){
        yield return null;
    }
    loaded = www.texture;
}
```